# Setting 2 parameters with single dataset in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

I've created a view that has 3 columns:

- label
- start_date
- end_date

For example (if today is 2018-04-11 10:12:54.4770000):

- Current Day, 2018-04-11 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-12 00:00:00.0000000
- Prior Day, 2018-04-10 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-11 00:00:00.0000000
- Last Week, 2018-04-02 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-09 00:00:00.0000000
- Last 7 Days (rolling), 2018-04-04 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-11 10:12:54.4770000
- Last Month, 2018-03-01 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-01 00:00:00.0000000
- Last Quarter, 2018-01-01 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-01 00:00:00.0000000
- Last Year, 2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
- WTD, 2018-04-08 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-11 10:12:54.4770000
- MTD, 2018-04-01 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-11 10:12:54.4770000
- QTD, 2018-04-01 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-11 10:12:54.4770000
- YTD, 2018-01-01 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-11 10:12:54.4770000
- Last 30 Days (rolling), 2018-03-12 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-11 10:12:54.4770000
- Last 90 Days (rolling), 2018-01-11 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-11 10:12:54.4770000
- Last 365 Days (rolling), 2017-04-11 00:00:00.0000000, 2018-04-11 10:12:54.4770000

And so on. So my goal is to provide user dropdown with the labels displayed and when he picks any, I would like to assign @start_date and @end_date parameters to use in other datasets. Any suggestions what can I do?

Comment: What are all the labels you're trying to display in the dropdown? Also, is the end_date always today's date and the start_date is the first date that falls within the label's description (first day of current week, first day of current year, etc.)?

Comment: @tingo I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Add a dataset called say `dsDropDown` and set the query to something like

`SELECT * FROM myView`

Add a parameter `myParameter` to your report and set the available values to your `dsDropDown` dataset. As you don't have a key you'll need to set the Value and Label properties both to your `label` field.

Next, add your main dataset and join to your view, filtering by the view label, something like.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM myTable t
        JOIN myView v on t.SomeDate >= v.start_date AND t.SomeDate <= v.end_date
WHERE v.label = @myParameter
```

Make sure the parameter name in the dataset query matches the parameter name EXACTLY (they are case sensitive).

Next just add your tablix/matrix/chart etc and point it to your main dataset.

I think that should be it but this was off the top of my head so it may not be 100% correct. Hopefully enough for you to follow though.

**Update after OP response:**
If you need these are parameters then you will need to add two new datasets, `dsStart` and `dsEnd`. The query for these datasets will be as follows..

```
SELECT start_date from myView WHERE label = @myParameter
```

and

```
SELECT end_date from myView WHERE label = @myParameter
```

Then add two new parameters `@start' and`@end` and set the default values to the respective datasets.

When you select your first parameter, the seconds two will be updated automatically. You can set the @start and @end parameters to hidden once you confirm its working.

Then change the main dataset query to something like..

```
SELECT * 
        FROM myTable t
    WHERE t.Somedate between @start AND @end
```

Comment: That would work,  but the bad thing is that I will not get start_date and end_date as params. So, in case if I'll need to use these date ranges with different date columns, then I'll need to join this view multiple times

Comment: thanks, but I wanted to do it with single dataset. Check my answer how I achieved that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question. "Alan Schofield" version works, but I wanted to do it with single dataset. So, what I did:

1. Added concatenated column to dataset that have start and end dates in it, for example: "2018-04-11 00:00:00.0000000|||2018-04-12 00:00:00.0000000"
2. Create 2 internal params with **default value** as `=Split(Parameters!date_selector.Value,"|||")(0)` and `=Split(Parameters!date_selector.Value,"|||")(1)` accordingly

That's it